# Why does text print out of place on a cloud console but not via SSH?

Tags: text, ssh, console, vi, vps

I use linode.com, a popular provider of Linux services.  I can login via SSH and run vi on text files no problems.  My local box is Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome and I can vi text files normally as well there.  But if I click on their console login button using Firefox (latest) I get a window which looks like it's 80x24 in size.  Everything appears normally, however the moment I edit via vi and move the cursor to edit a line of text the vi prints random words from other lines of that file next to the cursor.  It feels like it's wrapping on the wrong line and providing additional lines next to the cursor.  Someone told me to adjust the serial (TTYS) settings and try changing rows and columns.  I tried 20 or 24, but nothing works.  I am curious how to diagnose this problem and with what Linux commands to solve it.  Because it is definintely a compatibility between the local settings and the local, I just don't know Linux well enough.  You can tell me to ask Linode for assistance, which I did and will solve it, but this is a general problem in the Linux community, as this is the fifth provider of VPS services where I have this problem, and no amount of Binging around has solved the problem.